# Linear bounded operators in $l^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I'd appreciate some assistant to solve the following problem:

> Let $H=l^2(\mathbb{N})$. If $N\geq1$ and $f:H\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ defined by $f(x)=f((x_j)_j)=\alpha x_N+x_{N+1}$, where $\alpha$ is a given complex scalar.
> i. Prove that $f∈H'$, where $H'$ represents the set of all bounded linear operators in $H$.
> ii. Find $h_0∈H$ such that $f(x)=<x,h_0>$ for any $x∈H$. Is $h_0$ unique?

I already proved part i. But I'm not sure how to proceed on part ii.

Thank you.

Comment: Is $N$ some fixed number?

Comment: Try it with $N=2$ or something.  See if you can find $h_0$ in simple cases like that.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x):=x_1=\langle x,e_1\rangle$ and let $L,R$ be the left/right-shift operators.

Then $f=g\circ(\alpha L^N+L^{N+1})$ is the composition of linear continuous operators, hence itself a bounded functional. Moreover, if $\phi^*$ is the vector associated with the functional $\phi$, then $$f(x)=\langle x,f^*\rangle=\langle x,(gT)^*\rangle=\langle x,T^*g^*\rangle$$ so

$$h_0=f^*=(\alpha I+L)^*(L^*)^N\circ g^*=(\bar{\alpha}I+R)R^Ne_1=\bar{\alpha}e_N+e_{N+1}$$